# How to prove that $N_g\equiv ||\cdot ||_{\infty}$ iff $g^{-1}(\{0\})=\emptyset$?

Tags: normed-spaces

Let $E=\mathcal{C}[0,1]$, and $g\in E$, define $N_{g}(f)=||fg||_{\infty}$, the I have to prove that $N_g$ is equivalent to $||\cdot||_{\infty}$ iff $g^{-1}(\{0\})=\emptyset$.

The $'\Leftarrow'$ direction, is easy because if you take $a=\min_{t\in[0,1]}|g(t)|>0$ and $b=\max_{t\in[0,1]}|g(t)|>0$  then, $a||f||_{\infty}\leq ||fg||_{\infty}\leq b||f||_{\infty}$.

But I'm stuck in $'\Rightarrow'$ direction. 
Any help will appreciated, thanks!

Note. $N_g$ is a norm, because $g^{-1}(\{0\})$ has empty interior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $g(x_0) = 0$, then for $\epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ such that
$$
|x-x_0| < \delta \Rightarrow |g(x)| < \epsilon
$$
Choose $f \in E$ such that $\|f\|_{\infty} = 1$, and
$$
f(x) = 0 \text{ if } |x-x_0| \geq \delta
$$
Then $\|fg\|_{\infty} < \epsilon$. Hence, there is no $a>0$ such that
$$
a\|f\|_{\infty} \leq \|fg\|_{\infty} \quad\forall f\in E
$$

Comment: Very nice!! Thanks!